# jQuery jtable json, cyrillic encoding

Tags: jquery, json, gson, jquery-jtable, cyrillic

I have a problem with sending data from server to page.

If I send:

```
{
 "Result":"OK",
 "Records":[
  {"PersonId":1, "Name":"Benjamin Button", "Age":17, "RecordDate":"\/Date(1320259705710)\/"},
  {"PersonId":2, "Name":"Douglas Adams", "Age":42, "RecordDate":"\/Date(1320259705710)\/"},
  {"PersonId":3, "Name":"Isaac Asimov", "Age":26, "RecordDate":"\/Date(1320259705710)\/"},
  {"PersonId":4, "Name":"Thomas More", "Age":65, "RecordDate":"\/Date(1320259705710)\/"}
 ]
}
```

Everything is OK, when I replace *name* to any cyrillic word it is viewed as

```
????????? ??? ?
```

At the top of every jsp page I put

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
```

From server side I send

```
    String a = new Gson().toJson(rowsList);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("{\"Result\" : \"OK\", \"Records\" : ");
    sb.append(a);
    sb.append("}");
    return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in Spring MVC.

The solution reference
[is here](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/29395/java-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-spring-3-mvc)

Sending the responce as **ResponseEntity** object helped me

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/reference-table/load")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> loadReferenceTable() {

    List rowsList = genericDao.selectAllRecords(ReferenceViewEntity.class.getName());

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("{\"Result\" : \"OK\", \"Records\" : ");
    sb.append(new Gson().toJson(rowsList));
    sb.append("}");
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(sb.toString(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```